# JQuery - Double Click Google chrome to errors div appear

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, authentication, click

```js
$('#login').click(function () {
    
    var user = $('#user_email').val();
    var pwd = $('#pwd').val();
    
    if(user != "test" || pwd != "test"){
         $('#errors').html("Error");
    }else{
          $('#errors').html("Hello");
    }
    
   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Login:</legend>Email:
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="user_email" value="">
    <br>Password:
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="pwd" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="login" type="submit" value="Submit">
</fieldset>
<div id="errors"></div>
```

when i run this code on google chrome, first time i put wrong credentials, the error div appears and disappears automatically. Second time error div appears and stay. Why is it happening only on google chrome. Firefox works well.

Comment: what you have used for making the error div fade for the first time.

Comment: check your console have any error???

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/c2bs2v05/)**

First of all you need to add some `css` to hide or show a `div` like one below:

```
#errors{
    display:none;
}
```

Then `show` or `hide` it with 5 seconds delay or whatever time you want as below:

```
$('#login').click(function () {
    var user = $('#user_email').val();
    var pwd = $('#pwd').val();
    if(user != "test" || pwd != "test"){
         $('#errors').html("Error").show('slow').delay(5000).hide('slow');//delay here is 5 seconds and so its value is 5000
    }else{
          $('#errors').html("Hello").show('slow').delay(5000).hide('slow');//same as above
    }
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem on chrome. First time you click to submit error div appears and disappears.

Comment: did you check the demo above?? I tested it in chrome!!

Comment: So you don't want it to disappear??

Comment: in jsfiddle works fine. But if you try to create a file and run it on chrome, you need to click twice for error div appears

Comment: You mean create an html file and run it on chrome??

Comment: Correct! Creating an html file and running on chrome

Comment: Honestly speaking!! I just created it and I couldn't replicate the problem!!